Null value for a double integral
This question is correlated with this: Clarifications on the solution of a double integral: $\iint_X\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$.
If I consider
$$
\int_1^{2\cos\vartheta}r^2dr\underbrace{\left(\int_{-\frac\pi3}^{\frac\pi3}\cos^2\vartheta\sin\vartheta \ d\vartheta\right)}_{=0} =0
$$
I obtain hence a null  value: my integrand
$$\int_{-\frac\pi3}^{\frac\pi3}\cos^2\vartheta\sin\vartheta \ d\vartheta$$ is an odd function because it is the times of a even and odd function. Integrating an odd function over a symmetric domain gives $0$. If I consider
\begin{align*}&\int_{-\frac\pi3}^{\frac\pi3}\cos^2\vartheta\sin\vartheta\ d\vartheta \left(\int_1^{2\cos\vartheta}r^2dr\right)\\
&=\int_{-\frac\pi3}^{\frac\pi3}\cos^2\vartheta\sin\vartheta\ d\vartheta\cdot \left(\frac{8\cos ^3\vartheta-1}{3}\right)\\
&=0\end{align*}
same considerations for it.
Is it possible that the double integral is $0$?

The first integral does not make sense. What is $\vartheta$ in the upper limit?

Also, the original integral is over an odd function in $y$. So for any $x$, the integral over $y$ is $0$.

@Andrei I hope that I have done right the steps. Thank you very much for your support and comments.

Let's assume for a second that the integral over $\vartheta$ is a non-zero constant  $C$ in the first expression. Then the integral over $r$ would still give you a value that is dependent on $\vartheta$. What is the meaning of $\vartheta$ in that expression? You can integrate $r$ between $1$ and $2$, but then the limits of $\vartheta$ will depend on $r$.

@Andrei I have done an edit. I hope that now is more right.

Just because you get the right answer, it is not more right. Please answer what would your expression be if the inner integral is $1$. Let's assume for a second that you integrate the angular part on a non-symmetric interval

If you want to switch the order of integration so that you integrate with respect to $ r $ after integrating with respect to $ \vartheta $, you can do so, but you won't have $ \vartheta $ appearing in the bounds on $ r $.  You have to solve $ r \leq 2 \cos \vartheta $ for $ \vartheta $ and otherwise move things about, and you end up with $ \int _ 0 ^ 2 r ^ 2 , \mathrm d r , \big ( \int _ { - ! \arccos ( r / 2 ) } ^ { \arccos ( r / 2 ) } \cos ^ 2 \vartheta \sin \vartheta , \mathrm d \vartheta \big ) $.  And now you can argue that the inner integral must be $ 0 $.

@TobyBartels Thank you very much.

The answer that you accepted in the linked question asks you to integrate
$$\tag1
\int_{-\frac\pi3}^{\frac\pi3}\left(\int_1^{2\cos\vartheta}\cos^2\vartheta\sin\vartheta r^2\,\mathrm dr\right)\, \mathrm d\vartheta\,.
$$
Even if we write this in a notation that it popular in physics,
$$\tag2
\int_{-\frac\pi3}^{\frac\pi3}\, \mathrm d\vartheta\int_1^{2\cos\vartheta}\,\mathrm dr\;(\cos^2\vartheta\sin\vartheta r^2)\,,
$$
I don't see how we get your
$$\tag{what on earth ist this?}
\int_1^{2\cos\vartheta}r^2dr\left(\int_{-\frac\pi3}^{\frac\pi3}\cos^2\vartheta\sin\vartheta \ d\vartheta\right)\,.
$$
Hint. The integral in (1) can be written as
$$\tag3
\int_{-\frac\pi3}^{\frac\pi3}\underbrace{\cos^2\vartheta\sin\vartheta\left(\int_1^{2\cos\vartheta}r^2\,\mathrm dr\right)}_{\textstyle\text{is this perhaps an odd function in $\vartheta$?}}\, \mathrm d\vartheta\,.
$$
Edit. I see that in the end you did it right but your first expression is so confusing that one stops reading right there.

+1. I have done an edit. Is it correct now?

@Sebastiano Incorrect. Did you understand what in the linked answer (formula (1)) is the outer integral and what is the inner integral? Awaiting your response.

I have not understood. You have put $d\vartheta$ in (3) to the end. The integral with the limits $-\pi/3$ and $\pi/3$ before, Thus the 2nd integral in $[1,2\cos\vartheta]$ not depends by $\vartheta$ but only from $r$. If again I make a mistake please, edit my question or edit your answer. I not know well the english language :-(. Hence I understood only with an example. Excuse me very much.

What is the correct position of the integranda function and  of the differential?

See formula (1) above. I'll drop out of this, unless you tell me in words (choose English or Italian) what that formula means.

The $(1)$ is not written correctly because it is not well understood what to integrate. The choice of what to integrate before and after is not well intuited. Parentheses are needed.

Parentheses are not needed but don't hurt. I added them hoping to get your answer to my socratic questions. What do you integrate?
